# Connecting to a file store through a VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, http, remote-access, amazon-web-services

For an assignment, I have to build a service for the "road warriors" of a theoretical company. Basically, they need remote access to a file store or share that has to go through a VPN in the cloud. I've built an openVPN server in AWS, but I am not certain about the next step. My teacher vaguely suggested just having an HTTP server with a directory for the remote users to access through the VPN. So I was thinking of launching another EC2 instance and setting it up as an Apache web server, and getting the VPN to route to that. The question is, how do I get the users to be able to upload and download files to and from the directory on the web server?

Answer (score 1):

You could use WebDAV to upload files over HTTP(S) – it's natively supported by Windows *(though I'd rather use WinSCP for it)* and most other operating systems.

For systems without WebDAV support, there are many HTML-based file manager apps.

---

Alternatively, you could set up Samba as a fileserver for Windows' native "file sharing", since it also has wide support. (In fact you could do both – Samba over VPN, HTTP/DAV over VPN, and HTTPS/DAVS over Internet?)